# pylatex Change Font

Tags: python, pylatex

How do I change the font to "helvetica" in pylatex ?

I tried it, but this does not worK:

```
doc = pylatex.Document(fontenc = 'helvet')
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The font encoding has nothing to do with the font name. I do not know pylatex that well, but can't you simply include a font package (`\usepackage` in LaTeX)?

Comment: @TeXnician Thank you for your comment. This would be helpful, but I don't know how to do it in pylatex.

Comment: According to the docs it is possible to append packages and raw LaTeX strings, but as this solely revolves around Python and a library I'm voting to close as off-topic. Maybe you should simply ask the question how to include a package as issue.

Comment: Try `doc.preamble.append(Command('usepackage', 'helvet'))` in your python code.

Comment: @Skillmon Yes ! This works ! Thank you very much. I just had to add 'pl.' in front of 'Command' to make it work: 'doc.preamble.append(pl.Command('usepackage', 'helvet'))'

Comment: @Skillmon Can you add it as answer, such that I can accept it ?

Comment: @Skillmon I am also trying to make a black horizontal line spanning the page. I tried: doc.append(pl.Command('noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}'))  but it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add stuff to your preamble using `doc.preamble.append()`. To add `helvet` to your preamble use:

```
doc.preamble.append(Command('usepackage', 'helvet'))
```

This needs

```
from pylatex import Command
```

to work out, if you imported `pylatex` and not only submodules and functions from it, use `pylatex.Command` instead.

From what I gathered by a quick look on the documentation of `pylatex` you might be able to add arbitrary stuff to your document (making a horizontal line possible) by doing:

```
from pylatex.utils import NoEscape
```

and then

```
doc.append(NoEscape(r'\hrule')) # or whichever macro you want to use for your horizontal line
```

I'm not sure what `NoEscape` is needed for, perhaps it isn't needed, but I can't try because I don't have `pylatex` installed.

Comment: This is great ! Thank you very much ! Just a quick question: How can I change the thickness of the line ? I tried "doc.append(pl.Command('rule','0.4pt','\linewidth'))" but it does not work.

Comment: I also tried: doc.append(NoEscape(r'\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}'))

Comment: @james I don't know and I can't test as I don't have it up and running. I tried to set it up but got an error just from importing it so I didn't investigate any further. In LaTeX you'd change the arguments of `\rule` to be greater than `0.4pt`. You could try `\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}` for example.

Comment: If you do mean the thickness of the `\hrule` you can change it using `\hrule width \textwidth height 1pt depth 1pt`. It is a TeX primitive so has a very different syntax from `\rule`.

Comment: Thank you ! How would you translate the pure latex syntax "\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}" to the pylatex syntax ? BTW: just use pip install pylatex

Comment: @james I thought `NoEscape` does this. I can't really help you with `pylatex` as I already mentioned as I can't test anything I say. In Python you could create LaTeX syntax using the raw strings (so using the `r"<string>"` notation). If `NoEscape(r"\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}")` doesn't work then I have no idea.

Comment: You are awesome ! Thank you so much ! Yes, this works !

Comment: Maybe... you know how to tackle this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452105/pylatex-extend-textfield-height-to-bottom-of-the-page